# Voltage multiplier problem

Tags: diodes, spice, orcad

I´m working on a voltage multiplier with 5 stages. I am using the same value for all capacitors.

I think that my problem is the current load but I actually think that with a resistor in the output of the multiplier but this doesn't work.

I actually calculated the output with the ideal equation (5*Vin)-(((n-1)/(c*f))*Ioutput).The output multiplier should be 5 times the input voltage.

[image]

How I should calculate the value of the load resistor and is the schematic that I made wrong?

[image]

[image]

Taken of https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N4001-D.PDF

Comment: Your post is very unclear and you haven't asked a question. Are you really driving a multiplier with 100 mV power source as shown in your schematic?

Comment: You refer to "my problem", but you never say what it is.  What do you expect to see, and how does what you are seeing differ from what you expect?

Comment: @TimWescott I should expect in the output 5 times the value of the AC voltage source

Comment: First, please put that in your question.  Second, what does a 1N4001 do when you forward-bias it by 0.1V?

Answer (score 1):

As prompted a couple of times in the comments, the Typical Forward Voltage chart you've added shows that at room temperature you need 0.8 V to get any significant current through those diodes. You are only feeding the circuit with 100 mV hence the diodes don't conduct and you don't get any multiplication.

Your ideal equation

$$ V_{out} = 5V_{in}-\frac {n-1}{Cf}I_{out} $$

(which I haven't verified) does not account for diode voltage drops, as far as I can see. The equation will only hold true when V<sub>in</sub> >> 0.8 V.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, is isnt working yet but i will keep trying it

Comment: What are you going to try next?

Comment: Make the real equation and try but im stuck and i dont know now how to do to this

Comment: Can you not see that your input voltage is too low? You need more like 5 to 10 V instead of 100 mV input.